# Is there a free oracle product for trial/development?

Tags: database

I have some vague memory that there was a limited use license of a version of oracle so you could try it out on a small installation to try it out. Does such a beast still exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're referring to is called Oracle Express Edition, which can be found here:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/index.html

Basically, there are some limitations which I don't quite remember the details of, but I think you're limited to 4 GB database. In addition, the Express Edition is available only for versions up to Oracle 11.

This link contains good info on the differences from standard Oracle DB:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/pdf/dbxe_faq.pdf

Comment: I've used this before. It is not a trial, but does have some limitations. Which are unlikely to be a problem if using for development purposes. Anything you get working with this, should be able to work with the real deal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, get the developer license http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/index.html